# Android shell command/script to turn on reverse wireless charging

Tags: android, adb, termux

Any shell command to turn on reverse wireless charging? Like how we can control wifi from shell.

Comment: Even if Wifi and wireless charging are both wireless they are totally different technologies.  So concluding that as Wifi allows to open a hotspot something similar works for wireless charging is wrong. First you have to check if the used wireless charging systemin your phone supports working as power sender at all. If the hardware doesn't support it searching for a software switch is useless.

Comment: @Robert Phone does support it. It's just my use case require to run a shell script to turn it on. I have pixel6.

Comment: Wireless charging is hardware dependent so the setting might be hardware dependent as well, so you should include the phone model, manufacturer and Android version. Second SO is a site for programming, your question seems to be not really programming related, thus it should better be posted on https://android.stackexchange.com.